# Сам написал, и не понимаю как работает

Tags: javascript

Не понимаю работу функции

```
`var count = 1;
function increaseSpeedMoving() {
    if(count < 10) {
        clearInterval(timeoutId);
        setInterval(moveBySquad, 10);
        $("#main_header").text(count);
        count++;
    }
}
$("#main_header").click(increaseSpeedMoving);
`,
```

При каждом клике она уменьшает setIntreval все меньше и меньше(50-40-30-20-10), хотя вроде такого быть не должно, прошу объяснить почему так происходит.

```js
var direction = "right";
var counter = 0;
function moveBySquad() {
 if(direction === "right") {
  $("#main_header").offset({left: counter});//#main_header - if заголовка
  counter++;
  if(counter > 200) {
   counter = 0;
   direction = "down";
  }
 }
 if(direction === "down") {
  $("#main_header").offset({top: counter});
  counter++;
  if(counter > 200) {
   counter = 200;
   direction = "left";
  }
 }
 if(direction === "left") {
  $("#main_header").offset({left: counter});
  counter--;
  if(counter === 0) {
   counter = 200;
   direction = "up";
  }
 }
 if(direction === "up") {
  $("#main_header").offset({top: counter});
  counter--;
  if(counter === 0) {
   counter = 0;
   direction = "right";
  }
 }
}
var timeoutId = setInterval(moveBySquad, 50);
var count = 1;
function increaseSpeedMoving() {
 if(count < 10) {
  clearInterval(timeoutId);
  setInterval(moveBySquad, 10);
  $("#main_header").text(count);
  count++;
 }
}
$("#main_header").click(increaseSpeedMoving);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #222">
 <h1 id="main_header" >Title</h1>
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не уменьшает. Она у Вас при каждом вызове создает новый таймер, который никогда не удаляется. И множество таймеров, работающих одновременно, создают иллюзию уменьшения интервала.

Answer (score 3):

```
    clearInterval(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setInterval(moveBySquad, 10); // !!!
```