# Остановить setinterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

День добрый. Подскажите, можно ли как нибудь остановить таймер, если он задан как `setInterval("ФУНКЦИЯ()", 3000);` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var timer = setInterval(ФУНКЦИЯ, 3000);
clearInterval(timer);
```

Comment: Видимо вы готовы хоть каждый день на данный вопрос отвечать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1038266/256824

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов снимаю шляпу :))

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов видно что у Вас можно поучиться не только программированию :))